# How to make executable examples for functions that rely on console interaction?

Tags: r, console, package, cran

I submitted a package to CRAN that contains three functions. Each of these functions rely on console interaction to properly execute. I am having trouble with writing examples in the .Rd files because of the interactive nature of these functions. Specifically, `menu()` and `readline()`, both used heavily in my package, are giving me problems.  When running `devtools::check()`, I get an error regarding the examples, stating "menu() cannot be used non-interactively."

I tried to take a shortcut by writing out directions to run each function as comments in the `@examples` field, e.g.

```
@examples #Run my_function()
#When prompted with 'Question?', type '2' and press Enter
```

This workaround was not accepted by CRAN. Any suggestions?

Comment: First of all, your functions should check if they are called in interactive mode. If not, they should not call `menu` but return an error or do something else. Also, please don't submit to CRAN unless your package passes all checks (including on R-devel).

Comment: @Roland: I don't think I was clear in my question (which I have added upon). My package passes all of the checks, and my functions work properly. Because the functions are interactive, my examples in the .Rd files are not executable. I wrote the examples section of the .Rd files as comments as a workaround, but CRAN wants me to have actual examples

Comment: Well, that's not what Writing R Extensions tells you to do. I believe you should use `\donttest` but I'd have to look at what other packages do if I was in your position. The only one I know off the top of my head is the HMR package and it uses `\dontrun`, but I know the package author doesn't necessarily follow best practice.